# Question about sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

A friend of mine asked me to help with this problem. I tried induction, but I didn't know how to get this formula.

> If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers such that $xy= ax+by$. Show that
>   $$
> x^ny^n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{2n-1-k \choose n-1}(a^n b^{n-k}x^k+ a^{n-k}b^n y^k), \forall n  \geq 0
> $$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How is this related to computer science?

Comment: It is a question from "Concrete Mathematics, A Foundation for Computer Science".

Comment: I removed the ([tag:computer-science]) tag.

Comment: I'm doubtful about the validity of the equation for $n=0$, but that's a minor nitpick.

Answer (score 3):

$1=\frac{b}{x}+\frac{a}{y}$. So, let $s=\frac{b}{x}, t=\frac{a}{y}$. It is enough to show that $$2=\sum_{k=-\infty}^n \binom{2n-1-k}{n-1}( s^n t^{n-k}+s^{n-k} t^n).$$ Now, let $m=n-k$. Then $$ RHS= (st)^n \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \binom{n-1+m}{m} (s^{m-n}+t^{m-n})=2.$$
Note that $$(1-z)^{-n}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \binom{n-1+m}{m} z^m.$$

Comment: Thanks. But Why is the LHS of the first identity is $2$, and why does the sum start from $-\infty$

Answer (score 2):

Hint : Replace $(xy)^n$ (LaTeX notation) on the left by $(ax+by)^n$ expand the left-hand side using the Newton formula, and replace products $x^i y^j$ by $(ax+by)^{min(i,j)},$ etc. Nice exercice !

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But how can I shorten the expression after that?